# How to change permissions on mounted windows share?

Tags: mount, permissions, samba, fstab

I have mounted a windows share, But only root have write permissions..

I need to change that to my user so my programs can download and save stuff to my windows share.

commands I've have used to mount:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/ussenterprise
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
//servername/sharename  /mnt/ussenterprise  cifs  username=msusername,password=mspassword,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0
sudo mount -a
```

yes I have read access to everything in the mounted share, but only root gave write..

I've tried: `sudo chown user:user /mnt/ussenterprise`, and `sudo chown user /mnt/ussenterprise`

I get; `permissions denied`

what to do?

Comment: Maybe this saves some time to people...I made the changes mentioned above, and also added the uid and gid params in the answer below, but it wasn't working...until I unmounted and mounted again the share

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I changed my `/etc/fstab` to:

```
//server/share  /media/share  cifs  username=msusername,password=mspassword,uid=1000,gid=1000  0  0
```

Answer (score 2):

Your entry in `fstab` is creating the mount point in `/mnt`. Using the `/mnt` directory should only work if the drive is a local volume rather than a network share or removable device.

Edit your `fstab` entry to:

```
//servername/sharename  /media/ussenterprise  cifs  username=msusername,password=mspassword,umask=002,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0
```

This assumes that your uid and gid are 1000 which is the first default user and group IDs.  Then use:

```
sudo umount /media/ussenterprise
sudo mkdir /media/ussenterprise
sudo chown user:user /media/ussenterprise
sudo chmod 755 /media/ussenterprise
mount -a
```

This should mount the share with your user ID and permissions set to read/write.

Comment: sorry the entry in fstab was only a copy/paste of a guid, i have used "mnt/ussenterprise" ..

Comment: Change your `fstab` to make the mount in `/media` and run the commands I listed. I have a network cifs share mounted exactly like this.

Comment: Still only have read :(

Comment: when i run the mount command, i lose all permissions to root

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /media` ?

Comment: einar@Test:~$ ls -l /media
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 20 01:59 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 18 22:04 ussenterprise
einar@Test:~$

Comment: cdrom and ussenterprise

Comment: See my answer edits. Changes to the `fstab` entry should make the mount read/write for you.

Comment: hmm when i mount without sudo i get, "only root can do that"

Comment: Yes, if you unmount the volume and then try to remount it it will have to be done with `sudo` as the `fstab` and /media are owned by root.

Comment: i get: einar@ubuntutest:~$ sudo mount -a
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

Comment: What does the entry to mount in `fstab` read?

Comment: Not sure what u ment there.

Comment: In your /etc/fstab file, what is the current command to mount the share?

Comment: this is my fstab entery:
#windows share

//192.168.1.4/share/utorrent  /media/ussenterprise/utorrent  cifs  username=administrator,password=Ducktape13,umask=002,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0

then i hit f3 to save, and the i hit sudo mount -a
thank you for being so patience with me :)

Comment: I don't think that you can add mounts in subdirectories - e.g. `/media/ussenterprise/utorrent` and that my be what's throwing the syntax error.

Comment: I tried with and without /utorrent... with you fstab sugdestion.
If i use the ubuntuWIKI enter with and without /utorrent it works..
but only with read:(

Comment: for the record, i am use my ms admin username and password in the fstab

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l /media`?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb  7 21:17 cdrom
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 Feb  7 21:16 floppy -> floppy0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb  7 21:16 floppy0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 8192 Jan 30 18:06 ussenterprise

Comment: I could add you on skype, if you would like to take a closer look, and i maybe could give you ssh accsess ?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why it's creating the mount as owned by `root` when you have settings otherwise in the `fstab` entry..

Comment: Have you installed the `cifs-utils`? By all reason, the `fstab` entry should work to give you read/write access to the share.

Comment: yes i have cifs-utils

Answer (score 1):

Try these options:

```
username=msusername,password=mspassword,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,nosetuids,noperm
```

(definitions of noperm and nosetuids are found in the mount.cifs manpage)

Also, think about using a credentials file instead of having your name/pw in the clear:

```
credentials=/home/<user>/.smbcredentials
```

since fstab can be read by all.

Comment: did not change anything, stil only read

Answer (score 1):

I hope you found out your answer by the way I think this issue is not related to samba option, I think this is for ntfs permission level.
In windows 10 you can right click on folder which you want to share between windows and linux base system and follow this path:

1. Go to properties
2. Click on sharing tab
3. Go to advanced sharing
4. Go to permission  and then give full control to everyone user

Comment: I found the answer as writen above "//server/share  /media/share  cifs  username=msusername,password=mspassword,uid=1000,gid=1000  0  0"

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

The section: 'Mount password protected network folders' got me READ access.
Then, adding:
The Section: 'Special permissions' got me WRITE and DELETE access.

My system info:
- Laptop: Kubuntu 16.04 (client)
- File server: Windows Vista (hosting shares)
- Domain controller: Windows Server 2003 (Active Directory, DNS, etc)