# Cannot view mounted drive contents in Sonarr/Radarr

Tags: server, permissions, mount

I've just recently built a home server, and went through all the steps of installing Sabnzbd, Sonarr, Radarr, and Plex. This time around, I decided to use Ubuntu 18.04.1 (as opposed to Windows Server 2016) and Docker.

The problem I am having is that when I go to add existing series and movies via Sonarr and Radarr, respectively, I am unable to locate the drive that the shows and movies are contained on. I have two drives apart from the main OS drive, and they separately contain movies and shows. They are set to automatically mount in the `/media/` directory with fstab. Plex is able to read these files, which I find odd. I know it's a permissions issue with the folders but I'm just having trouble configuring the folders' permissions. I have set the folder owner and group to my user account, but in WinSCP the folders still show the owner being root, not sure if that's a bug or not. How do I need to have these folders set up?

If you need any more information please let me know. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

1. Permissions according to `ls -la`:

`drwxrwxrwx   1 administrator root 131072 Oct 23 00:15 movies
drwxrwxrwx   1 administrator root  81920 Oct 23 19:03 tv`

2. FSTAB:

`UUID=E046167246164A24 /media/movies ntfs-3g permissions 0 1
UUID=1C5829AD5829871C /media/tv ntfs-3g permissions 0 1`

3. The drive format is NTFS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment, but:

1. And what are the permissions according to a real shell? (`ls -la`)
2. What are the settings in `/etc/fstab`? (Post the relevant line)
3. What is the drive format? (This is also noted in fstab, but to be sure: `sudo file -sL /dev/sd*`)

I'm guessing it's a problem like this one: [How to change permissions on mounted windows share?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393563/how-to-change-permissions-on-mounted-windows-share)

Comment: I edited the post!

Comment: I have also reformatted both hard drives to ext4 and have given both drives 0777 permissions along with assigning my user and group as the owners of the drives.


New Fstab:
`/dev/disk/by-uuid/a692986f-fa85-489d-9677-629baa76117e /mnt/a692986f-fa85-489d-$
/dev/disk/by-uuid/004d06fc-fe50-4cef-a630-1e83c01048d3 /mnt/004d06fc-fe50-4cef-$`. Also, Plex can still find the drives just fine, but they are in a directory not shown in Sonarr/Radarr: `/yourcomputer/mnt/a692986f-fa85-489d-9677-629baa76117e`. The /yourcomputer/ part doesn't show up at all.