# Can't write to smb share

Tags: permissions, kubuntu, samba

I'd like to be able to share files between my Kubuntu 19.10 machine and another machine with Windows 10 on it. So I set up a shared folder on the Windows machine.

From Kubuntu, I can get to the shared folder via Dolphin (the file manager). And if there are files in that folder, I can see them and copy them over. However, every time I try to put a file in it from Kubuntu, I get:

> Access denied. Could not write to smb://...

I realise this might be a common request, and before you satisfy that itch to mark this as a duplicate question, I'll point out that I have already tried a few things, such as modifying `/etc/fstab` (as per this [Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393563/how-to-change-permissions-on-mounted-windows-share)  and [MountWindowsSharesPermanently](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) - the latter did not even get me read access) or doing a `sudo cp` directly into the `smb://` folder where I already have access (`Cannot create regular file smb://.../test.txt: no such file or directory`).

I really don't know what else to try and would appreciate some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder that you cannot write to is in Windows right?
When you navigate to the shared folder's security tab on your Windows machine, who are the users and what privileges do they have? Which users have write access (ie: Users/Administrators)?

I can reproduce the same error as you when the entire folder is marked read-only but still shared on the Windows machine (just like the default settings on the `C:\Users\Public` folder).

How about try making a new folder in Windows, navigating to the security tab and add "Everyone" as a user - with full control for its access privileges. Then navigate to the Sharing tab and share that folder over the network. Do you get the same error when writing to it on your Kubuntu machine?

If this works, then I would make sure the credentials I'm inputting when I do `smb://<windows-machine-IP>/<sharedfolder>` is listed on that Security tab and has full control.

Comment: Thanks, yes it's on Windows and I did provide access to Everyone (sorry, I should have specified). I did notice when checking again that the folder is marked Read-Only, and seems to remain so even after I make it not Read-Only. I believe I've seen this quirk before but I'm not sure off-hand why it's happening.

Comment: The problem was indeed permission-related on Windows!